# API Design for Idiot-Proof Iteration Without Generics

Tags: java, .net, api, language-agnostic, api-design

When you're designing the API for a code library, you want it to be easy to use well, and hard to use badly.  Ideally you want it to be idiot proof.

You might also want to make it compatible with older systems that can't handle generics, like .Net 1.1 and Java 1.4.  But you don't want it to be a pain to use from newer code.

I'm wondering about the best way to make things easily iterable in a type-safe way...  Remembering that you can't use generics so Java's `Iterable<T>` is out, as is .Net's `IEnumerable<T>`.

You want people to be able to use the enhanced for loop in Java `(for Item i : items)`, and the `foreach` / `For Each` loop in .Net, and you don't want them to have to do any casting.  Basically you want your API to be now-friendly as well as backwards compatible.

The best type-safe option that I can think of is arrays.  They're fully backwards compatible *and* they're easy to iterate in a typesafe way.  But arrays aren't ideal because you can't make them immutable.  So, when you have an immutable object containing an array that you want people to be able to iterate over, to maintain immutability you have to provide a defensive copy each and every time they access it.

In Java, doing `(MyObject[]) myInternalArray.clone();` is super-fast.  I'm sure that the equivalent in .Net is super-fast too.  If you have like:

```
class Schedule {
   private Appointment[] internalArray;
   public Appointment[] appointments() {
       return (Appointment[]) internalArray.clone();
   }
}
```

people can do like:

```
for (Appointment a : schedule.appointments()) {
    a.doSomething();
}
```

and it will be simple, clear, type-safe, and fast.

But they *could* do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < schedule.appointments().length; i++) {
    Appointment a = schedule.appointments()[i];
}
```

And then it would be horribly inefficient because the entire array of appointments would get cloned twice for every iteration (once for the length test, and once to get the object at the index).  Not such a problem if the array is small, but pretty horrible if the array has thousands of items in it.  Yuk.

Would anyone actually do that?  I'm not sure...  I guess that's largely my question here.

You could call the method `toAppointmentArray()` instead of `appointments()`, and that would probably make it less likely that anyone would use it the wrong way.  But it would also make it harder for people to find when they just want to iterate over the appointments.

You would, of course, document `appointments()` clearly, to say that it returns a defensive copy.  But a lot of people won't read that particular bit of documentation.

Although I'd welcome suggestions, it seems to me that there's no perfect way to make it simple, clear, type-safe, *and* idiot proof.  Have I failed if a *minority* of people are unwitting cloning arrays thousands of times, or is that an acceptable price to pay for simple, type-safe iteration for the *majority*?

---

NB I happen to be designing this library for both Java and .Net, which is why I've tried to make this question applicable to both.  And I tagged it language-agnostic because it's an issue that could arise for other languages too.  The code samples are in Java, but C# would be similar (albeit with the option of making the `Appointments` accessor a property).

---

**UPDATE**: I did a few quick performance tests to see how much difference this made in Java.  I tested:

1. cloning the array once, and iterating over it using the enhanced for loop
2. iterating over an ArrayList using
   the enhanced for loop
3. iterating over an unmodifyable
   ArrayList (from
   Collections.unmodifyableList) using
   the enhanced for loop
4. iterating over the array the bad way (cloning it repeatedly in the length check
   and when getting each indexed item).

For 10 objects, the relative speeds (doing multiple repeats and taking the median) were like:

1. 1,000
2. 1,300
3. 1,300
4. 5,000

For 100 objects:

1. 1,300
2. 4,900
3. 6,300
4. 85,500

For 1000 objects:

1. 6,400
2. 51,700
3. 56,200
4. 7,000,300

For 10000 objects:

1. 68,000
2. 445,000
3. 651,000
4. 655,180,000

Rough figures for sure, but enough to convince me of two things:

- Cloning, then iterating is definitely
  not a performance issue.  In fact
  it's consistently faster than using a
  List.  (this is [why Java's
  enum.values() method returns a
  defensive copy of an array instead of
  an immutable list](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi_I7oD_uGI&t=58m25s).)
- If you repeatedly call the method,
  repeatedly cloning the array unnecessarily,
  performance becomes more and more of an issue the larger the arrays in question.  It's pretty horrible.  No surprises there.

Comment: Never underestimate the powers of idiocy...

Comment: @Marc that is generally my attitude.  It's tough to figure out where to draw the line when catering to it, if catering it makes things a little harder for everyone else.

Comment: actually most idiots are conscious enough to cache the result of `appointments()` in a local variable. some of them would even cache `[].length` too. even idiots are very defensive.

Answer (score 6):

clone() is fast but not what I would describe as super faster.

If you don't trust people to write loops efficiently, I would not let them write a loop (which also avoids the need for a clone())

```
interface AppointmentHandler {
    public void onAppointment(Appointment appointment);
}

class Schedule {
    public void forEachAppointment(AppointmentHandler ah) {
        for(Appointment a: internalArray)
            ah.onAppointment(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice pattern, but the downside is that I think it would confuse some people.  I updated my post to show results of a few tests that show that cloning and then iterating is OK performance wise.  But you're right that cloning isn't really super-fast, because if it was then there'd be no problem with repeatedly cloning in the loop.  And the tests show that clearly that has horrible results.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't really have it both ways, I would suggest that you create a pre generics and a generics version of your API.  Ideally, the underlying implementation can be mostly the same, but the fact is, if you want it to be easy to use for anyone using Java 1.5 or later, they will expect the usage of Generics and Iterable and all the newer languange features.

I think the usage of arrays should be non-existent.  It does not make for an easy to use API in either case.

NOTE: I have never used C#, but I would expect the same holds true.

Comment: This is a tempting approach - one that I may well follow.  The frustrating thing is that I have a good no-generics design for pretty much all the API, apart from a few objects that hold lists or arrays and that people need to be able to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

As far as failing a minority of the users, those that would call the same method to get the same object on each iteration of the loop would be asking for inefficiency regardless of API design. I think as long as that's well documented, it's not too much to ask that the users obey some semblance of common sense.